# Realm cocoa database growing significantly

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, realm

using realm in a multithreaded app and I'm finding that the app is growing significantly every few seconds while I update percentages in my downloads using the session download api. Code to update the bytes downloaded looks like this.

```
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{

            if(!restoreAsset.isInvalidated)
                restoreAsset.bytesDownloaded = totalBytesWritten;
        }];
```

I'm running multiple threads, up to about 32 in some cases between uploads and downloads.

Am I doing something wrong here by using the default realm or how can I avoid all these threads duplicating their data because they are all accessing the same table or whatever the problem would be.

The database eventually get to over 2Giga bytes and crashes the app. I compact the database when the app is restarted but this doesn't seem to make any difference to the size of it. There is not many rows in the database, approx 1-2K rows max. Sometimes a lot less. Doesn't seem to matter.

Any help or guidelines on how to access the Realm across multiple threads is welcome because I can't seem to get this to work as expected.